# Heroku - heroku run python manage.py migrate error

Tags: python, django, heroku

Estoy tratando de migrar a través de heroku para loguearme con fb pero cuando ejecuto el comando `heroku run python manage.py migrate` sucede lo siguiente (se supone que ya realicé diployed en heroku):

```
>>> heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

> ```
> Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ afternoon-lake-17482... up, run.2063 (Free)
> /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py:808: RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead.
>     return meta(name, bases, d)
>
> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS:
> default.UserSocialAuth.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'UserSocialAuth.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserSocialAuth.user.
>     HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for UserSocialAuth.user' or 'UserSocialAuth.user.
> default.UserSocialAuth.user: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'UserSocialAuth.user' clashes with reverse query name for 'UserSocialAuth.user'.
>     HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserSocialAuth.user' or 'UserSocialAuth.user'.
> ```

Por favor, ¿tienen idea de lo que pueda hacer?, ya que apenas inicio en el mundo de django.

Answer (score 1):

No parece que sea un error propio de Heroku, sino que en cualquier intento de poner a funcionar tu código en otra computadora, saltarán esos errores.

Por lo visto tienes un problema con la definición de un modelo, específicamente uno que tiene 2 referencias (ForeignKey) al modelo UserSocialAuth.user. ¿Por qué se genera un problema ante una situación como esa?, veamos el siguiente ejemplo:

`class Clase1(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    u_creador = models.ForeignKey(Usuario)
    u_modificador = models.ForeignKey(Usuario)`

aquí, además, de la relación desde Clase1 a Usuario, se crea de forma automática una relación desde Usuario a Clase1, dicha relación podría usarse para responder a la pregunta ¿qué objetos de Clase1 están relacionados con el usuario X?; ahora bien, dicha pregunta plantea una duda, ¿se deben considerar sólo los objetos creados por el usuario X, sólo los modificados o ambos? Además, hay que aclarar que esa relación se genera de forma automática, asignando un nombre compuesto por los nombres de ambas clases (digamos que se llama `usuario_clase1`), y es allí donde se genera el error para Django, porque no puede utilizar el mismo nombre para la referencia de Usuario con el campo u_creador y para la referencia de Usuario con el campo u_modificador.

Ante este problema hay 2 soluciones posibles: especificar un nombre particular, para resolver el problema de Django; o indicar que no se requiere la creación de esa referencia opuesta, desde Usuario a Clase1. En ambos casos, se debe utilizar el argumento **related_name** para el campo ForeignKey, como se menciona en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

Comment: @LuisLI amigo te agradezco por la respuesta, pero debo decirte que en models.py no tengo aún nada, es lo que me parece extraño

Comment: ¿Estás usando python-social-auth?, porque aquí: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/551 se menciona parte del mensaje de error que obtienes. Y en el enlace principal: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth se menciona que esa librería ha quedado obsoleta, y se indica dónde buscar la nueva versión (que se supone no debe generar errores).

Comment: de nuevo gracias amigo, por supuesto estoy usando el python-social-auth, pero mira que me fijé en el segundo link acerca de la librería y la actualicé a la que allí dice, pero mira ahora me sale el siguiente error, y no me deja arrancar el servidor ni local ni desde heroku : {ImportError: No module named parse} que puede ser ahora?

Comment: el error me sale cuando intento migrar

Comment: Parece que te falta tener instalado el módulo parse. Normalmente en los proyectos python montados en github se especifica un archivo requirements.txt, el cual indica qué paquetes de python se necesitan tener instalados. El método para tenerlos instalados es ejecutar el comando `pip install -r requirements.txt`, donde requirements.txt es el nombre del archivo (en alguna ocasión podría ser un nombre un poco diferente). A pesar que ese comando instala lo necesario, te animo a que veas dicho archivo (requirements), para conocer un poco qué se va a instalar.

Comment: amigo esto es lo que tengo en requirements.txt: appdirs==1.4.3
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.9.5
gunicorn==19.7.1
oauthlib==2.0.2
packaging==16.8
PyJWT==1.4.2
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.21
python3-openid==3.1.0
requests==2.13.0
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
six==1.10.0
social-auth-app-django==1.1.0
social-auth-core==1.2.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
dj-database-url==0.4.0
psycopg2==2.6.1